# Change Chapter to custom .ttf font

Tags: fonts, luatex, chapters, texstudio

I am a n00b, and I started writing a large Document with Tex Live in TeXstudio while compiling with LuaLatTex. I am required to replace the Font of some Headings, especially, `\chapter` and `\Huge` with a special Company Font provided in `.ttf`.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Special Company Font}
```

I tried using fontspec, which only lets me change none KOMA-Script fonts.
I also tried using titlesec, which i can't use with this specific .ttf font.

Comment: Is this  a general problem or particular to the special company font? In the general case you should provide a minimal document showing how you tried to use a font via `fontspec` for headings.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I finally got the result I wanted with `fontspec`, `tocloft` and KOMA-Script. I will edit the question to show the solution i got soon.

Comment: Great! Please note that you can also add your solution as an answer. This makes it more transparent fro my point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to manipulate how to manipulate the Style of KOMA Script, as well as TOC, LOT and LOF, generated text, to a .ttf font. Additionally, the style of package `acronym` generated acronym lists.

First you need to add your font with `fontspec`. You need to use LuLaTex or XeTeX to use this package:

```
\usepackage(fontspec)
\newfontfamily{\fontarial}{Arial}
```

This Changes the KOMA-Script headings:

```
\setkomafont{chapter}{\fontarial\huge\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{section}{\fontarial\Large\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\fontarial\large\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{paragraph}{\fontarial\normalsize\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{subparagraph}{\fontarial\normalsize\mdseries}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\fontarial\small}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\fontarial\small}
\addtokomafont{footnote}{\fontarial\scriptsize}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\fontarial\scriptsize\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\fontarial\scriptsize}
```

Tho change the styling of TOC, LOT and LOF I recommend `tocloft`:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\fontarial\huge\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\fontarial\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\fontarial\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\fontarial}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\fontarial}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\fontarial}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\fontarial}
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\fontarial\huge\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\fontarial}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\fontarial}
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\fontarial\huge\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cfttabfont}{\fontarial}
\renewcommand{\cfttabpagefont}{\fontarial}
```

To change the font of a Biber generated bibliography:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize\fontarial}
\urlstyle{same}
\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished, online, book, incollection, article, misc, patent]{title}{\bfseries#1}
```

And at last, this is kinda tricky, changing the style of an Abbrevation page, generated with `acronym`:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/510502/198164