# Format Acronym description label in Abbrevation chapter

Tags: fonts, formatting, fontspec, acronyms

I want to format the whole label with a .ttf font, and got it to work mostly, only the marked part wont be formatted with aclabelfont:

[image]

I want to use the same `myfontfamily` (defined with fontspec) for both, only that the first part is bold, which already works as intended.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\myfontfamily#1}}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Abbrevation}
    \begin{acronym}[PPPPPPPP]
        \acro{test}[TEST]{Total Enlighning Setup Test}
    \end{acronym}

   \chapter{Chapter 1}
   This is a \ac{test}.

\end{document}
```

I do NOT want the content of `\ac{test}` to be formatted differently, tho, so it won't look any different to the rest of the text block.

I tried using `\acffont`, `\acfsfont` and `\acsfont`but did not achieve the wanted result. I really only want to format the red marked label in the Abbrevation Chapter.

Comment: Where and how do you define `\myfontfamily` command? Does it ends in `\selectfont`? If not... add a `\selectfont` even inside the command definition even in the command `\aclabelfont` definition after `\myfontfamily`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `acronym` package does not seem to have an interface for this. One possibility is to patch the command that actually is used for printing the list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec,etoolbox}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}


\newfontfamily\myfontfamily{Roboto}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\AC@@acro{] #3}{] \myfontfamily#3}{}{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\textbf{\myfontfamily#1}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Abbrevation}
\begin{acronym}[PPPPPPPP]
  \acro{test}[TEST]{Total Enlightening Setup Test}
\end{acronym}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
This is a \ac{test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

- The definition of the command `\AC@@acro` can be seen in the `acronym` manual.
- The command `\patchcmd` is explained in the `etoolbox` manual

Comment: Provides the exact result i wanted, works like a charm, thanks alot.